# Networking using a separate thread on iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, networking

The application that I develop is an iOS client that communicates with an OS X server. The current version of this application does all the networking logic on the main thread and this works fine for what I want to do.

However, in the next version, I want the networking logic be more flexible. For this to work, I would like to dedicate a separate thread to it, but I am not quite sure what solution is right for my needs.

At first, GCD looked like a good candidate, but it seems to only be suitable for chunks of work to be executed on a separate thread. What I would like to do is have all the networking logic on a separate thread. The connection between the iOS client and the OS X server is persistent and all the data streaming and processing should occur on that separate thread.

The question boils down to, what approach is most suitable for this scenario?

EDIT: To get rid of any confusion, the connection that I use makes use of sockets and NSStream instances. I am not dealing with connecting to a remote web server. In other words, AFNetworking and ASIHttpRequest are not an option for me.

Comment: Why don't you use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) or [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.org)

Comment: FYI - ASIHttpRequest is no longer being developed.

Comment: Yes I know, but what's the problem with that? Isn't it working as it is now? It is. That's why I also suggested AFNetworking...

Comment: I have edited the question to better describe the type of networking that I am talking about. AFNetworking and ASIHttpRequest are not an option for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can create a thread with runloop(we call it NetworkThread), running following code:

   ```
   while (!self.isCancelled) {
       NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
       [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
       [pool release];
   }
   ```
2. then you can use `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector onThread:(NSThread *)thr withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait` to perform your network request selector on NetworkThread.
3. All network callbacks will be called on NetworkThread, then processing your response data on NetworkThread, push final data to main thread, update UI.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking is awesome. Uses blocks and GCD.  I have written a NetworkClient class that makes calling it fairly simple.  Feel free to use it or customize it, but I don't warranty anything :)

The API Key is something that can be removed if this doesn't fit your needs.  I added it as a way to add security to all my network requests.  My web services check the validity of the passed in APIKey before returning anything.

Also, you can be fairly flexible in how you want things done.  You could do sync or async requests, requests that don't warn the user on failure, etc.

Basic Example usage:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"GetAllParkingLots", @"Command",
                                nil];

        [NetworkClient processURLRequestWithURL:nil andParams:params block:^(id obj) {
            // I check to see what kind of object is passed back, in this case I was expecting an Array
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                // Do something with the Array
                [self processNetworkRequestWithArray:(NSArray *)obj];
            }
        }];
```

NetworkClient.h:

```
//
//  NetworkClient.h
//
//  Created by LJ Wilson on 2/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 LJ Wilson All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString * const APIKey;

@interface NetworkClient : NSObject

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
             alertUserOnFailure:(BOOL)alertUserOnFailure
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)handleNetworkErrorWithError:(NSError *)error;

+(void)handleNoAccessWithReason:(NSString *)reason;

@end
```

NetworkClient.m:

```
//
//  NetworkClient.m
//
//  Created by LJ Wilson on 2/18/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 LJ Wilson All rights reserved.
//

#import "NetworkClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "SBJson.h"

#warning Set APIKey or set to nil
NSString * const APIKey = @"YourAPIKEYGoesHere";

@implementation NetworkClient

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {

    [self processURLRequestWithURL:url andParams:params syncRequest:NO alertUserOnFailure:NO block:^(id obj) {
        block(obj);
    }];
}

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {
    [self processURLRequestWithURL:url andParams:params syncRequest:syncRequest alertUserOnFailure:NO block:^(id obj) {
        block(obj);
    }];
}


+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
             alertUserOnFailure:(BOOL)alertUserOnFailure
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {

#warning Fix default url
    // Default url goes here, pass in a nil to use it
    if (url == nil) {
        url = @"YourDefaultURLGoesHere";
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:params];
    [dict setValue:APIKey forKey:@"APIKey"];

    NSDictionary *newParams = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];

    NSURL *requestURL;
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:requestURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:url parameters:newParams];

    __block NSString *responseString = @"";

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *_operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];
    __weak AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = _operation;

    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        responseString = [operation responseString];

        id retObj = [responseString JSONValue];

        // Check for invalid response (No Access)
        if ([retObj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            if ([[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Message"] isEqualToString:@"No Access"]) {
                block(nil);
                [self handleNoAccessWithReason:[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Reason"]];
            }
        } else if ([retObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            if ([(NSArray *)retObj count] > 0) {
                NSDictionary *dict = [(NSArray *)retObj objectAtIndex:0];
                if ([[dict valueForKey:@"Message"] isEqualToString:@"No Access"]) {
                    block(nil);
                    [self handleNoAccessWithReason:[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Reason"]];
                }
            }
        }
        block(retObj);
    } 
                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"Failed with error = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Error]:%@",error]);
                                          block(nil);
                                          if (alertUserOnFailure) {
                                              // Let the user know something went wrong
                                              [self handleNetworkErrorWithError:operation.error];
                                          }

                                      }];

    [operation start];

    if (syncRequest) {
        // Process the request syncronously
        [operation waitUntilFinished];
    } 


}


+(void)handleNetworkErrorWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Error]:%@",error];

    // Standard UIAlert Syntax
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" 
                            message:errorString 
                            delegate:nil 
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [myAlert show];

}

+(void)handleNoAccessWithReason:(NSString *)reason {
    // Standard UIAlert Syntax
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"No Access" 
                            message:reason 
                            delegate:nil 
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [myAlert show];

}


@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer. However, AFNetworking is not what I am looking for as I do not connect with a web server. I have used AFNetworking in past projects and it does indeed work great. For this application (as mentioned in the question), I communicate between and iOS client and an OS X server making use of Bonjour and low level socket APIs.