# Extending a class with delegate methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I would like to extend the ASIHTTPRequest class, yes I know it's not being developed anymore, but I have it through out my project and I don't have time to totally replace it yet. My reason for extending it is to provide a list of fail-over hosts.

My question has to do with the ASIHTTPRequest delegate methods, how do I inherit them in my extended class? Do I need to create another protocol?

Comment: I don't get your problem.  The compiler knows nothing of the delegate methods a class may call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same situation as you about 8 months ago.  I decided to bite the bullet and switch to AFNetworking and am sure glad I did.  Working with those delegate methods is a pain.  To answer your question, you would have to declare your class as a delegate for the methods you want to handle.

If you need help switching, [check out my NetworkClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224251/networking-using-a-separate-thread-on-ios) that I wrote to replace all the delegate method stuff in ASI.